# random sample per group, with min_rows

Tags: python, pandas, sample

I have a dataframe and I want to sample it. However while sampling it randomly I want to have at least 1 sample from every element in the column. I also want the distribution have an effect as well.(ex: values with more samples on the original have more on the sampled df)

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36390406/6692898) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49619681/6692898) question, but with minimum sample size per group.

Lets say this is my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['class'])
df['class'] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2]
df_sample = df.sample(n=4)
```

And when I sample this I want the df_sample to look like:

```
     Class
      0
      0
      1
      2
```

Thank you.

Comment: How about just use set to get all unique item and then use sample(n=len(set) -prev_n) to sampling from data.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @YukiShioriii you could :

1 - sample one row of each group of values

2 - randomly sample over the remaining rows regardless of the values

Answer (score 0):

Following YukiShioriii's and mprouveur's suggestion

```
# random_state for reproducibility, remove in production code
sample = df.groupby('class').sample(1, random_state=1)

sample = sample.append(
    df[~df.index.isin(sample.index)] # only rows that have not been selected
    .sample(n=sample_size-sample.shape[0]) # sample more rows as needed
).sort_index()
```

Output

```
    class
2       0
4       0
13      1
14      2
```